# Unable to deploy a helm chart from a local file due to template error

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I can run `helm install --name rabbitmq stable/rabbitmq` with no problems.

I want to download the chart and install it from local files. I get the tgz with `helm fetch stable/rabbitmq` then unzip it with `tar -xvzf rabbitmq-4.1.0.tgz --warning=no-timestamp`. Everything is now in a folder called rabbitmq (templates folder, Chart.yaml, values.yaml, etc)

Now if I run `helm install -n rabbitmq ./rabbitmq/ -f ./rabbitmq/values.yaml` I get:

`Error: render error in "rabbitmq/templates/configuration.yaml": template: rabbitmq/templates/configuration.yaml:18:48: executing "rabbitmq/templates/configuration.yaml" at <4>: invalid value; expected string`

That line 4 is `name: {{ template "rabbitmq.fullname" . }}-config`

Why isn't this value getting replaced properly? Is there some extra step I need to do when `helm install`ing a chart from local files?

Answer (score 3):

Well, the issue was that my values.yaml file I was using had values for rabbitmq helm v 4.0.1 and not 4.1.0. I fetched the 4.0.1 version and, after fixing an unrelated error in the template itself, resolved the issue.